# Compilation Error: Team City and Visual Studio 2012

Tags: tfs, teamcity, nuget-package

So I have build project on TeamCity 8.0.3 and have create two build steps.

1.) The first step is to Install all NuGet packages.
I have set my project up according to [this](http://jamesheppinstall.wordpress.com/2012/05/15/dependency-management-in-net-with-nuget-and-teamcity/) blog and if I run this step it works fine however I went over the logs and found: `[14:07:45][install] All packages listed in packages.config are already installed.` Is this OK?

2.) I have another step that is suppose to build my Class Library however I get a compilation error saying that references are missing even after step one, which is suppose to install the packages, has passed?

What am I doing wrong and should I provide more log details?

Comment: The message in the first step is perfectly normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated by Pedro, the first log message is absolutely normal.

For the second issue, it's not easy to throubleshoot a compilation error without logs :)

Often the issue is related to wrong checkout rules.
You can try to figure out what has been downloaded by teamcity by looking on the agent working directory (normally it is downloaded under c:\buildagent\work\'something', look at the build log to find out the actual folder).

Another common issue is that references are stored as absolute paths instead of relative paths: everything works on your machine, but teamcity builds on a different folder so referenced files can't be found... You have to open your csproj files with a text editor to find out if everything is ok.

Copy the entire folder on your machine and try to build it: are you able to reproduce the error?